# How to stream exporting of SQL Server schema to file

Tags: sql-server, database, schema, database-migration

We have a database having 200 000 stored procedures and 100 000 tables, exporting schema of this database failed with error

> System out of memory

in Mysql studio

Is there anyway to export schema with streaming to file instead of increasing memory to solve out of memory error?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of system has 100 000 tables in a schema?

Comment: Also, are you really working with SQL Server and using MySQL tools, or is either of them wrong here by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [DBDiff](https://github.com/OpenDBDiff/OpenDBDiff) we use in my company to detect changes in the DB's between Development / QA / Production that you may use by comparing the requested DB with a blank DB.